# How can I lose the cops?

Tags: retro-city-rampage

Other than picking up the little blue markers that make the cops lose site of you temporarily, are there any other ways to lose the cops in *Retro City Rampage*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this:

- Kill all of the cops on screen before more of them show up.
- Out run them while not killing people (or committing other crimes).
- Go into a building, and kill all the cops within the building then go back out.

[Source.](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/660947-retro-city-rampage/64304203)